# Multithreading with a multimap

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, producer-consumer

Enviroment : Windows 7.0 , C++ , Multithreading

I have created a new worker thread to receive data on socket and add it into a static `multimap` instance.

code snippet:

```
//remember mymultimap is static data type
static std::multimap<string,string> mymultimap;
EnterCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);
mymultimap.insert ( "aaa", "bbb") );
LeaveCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);
```

At same time my main thread is reading same static multimap :
code snap :

```
EnterCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);
std::multimap<string,string>::iterator it = mymultimap.begin();
for( ; it != mymultimap.end(); it++)
{
std::string firstName = (*it).first;
std::string secondName = (*it).second;
}
LeaveCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);
```

As the main and work threads are continously doing read and write, it hampers  my application peformance.
Also the instance of `multimap` contains huge data (more than 10,000 records).

How can I make thread lock for a minimal time in multimap?

```
EnterCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);
///minimal lock time for Map ???
LeaveCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);
```

Please help me in improve my application performance.

Comment: Depending on what you do in the loop, you could just copy the data to a second collection, and then perform the (possibly) lengthy operations on the copy, after you leave the critical section.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands your question leaves too much room for discussion: we don't know how the values stored in your multimap are actually used.

If:

- the order enforced in that data structure is important,
- you need to keep the values in the multimap even after they have been read,
- you need to go through all the entries each time you read,

then you are pretty much stuck as to how we can optimize the use of that structure.

On the other hand, if you can relax one of these requirements somehow, then you may have possibilities to optimize things a bit, for instance by using a message queue instead of the map directly for communication between both threads.

Message queues are a standard way to implement efficient communication between threads, and for one to one setup, there are even lockless solutions.

**Update**: thinking about it, sharing that type of structure accross threads is not a good idea, whatever use you make of it. It is better to regroup all accesses to a multimap within one single thread, and thus have items generated by other threads passed on to the thread managing it through a queue. This completely decouples the work of generating the items from their storage and use. In your case, the producer thread will lose less time storing the data, which leaves it more time to handle the socket stream.

So, for that solution, you need a `queue<std::pair<key,value> >`, say `std::queue`, to be handled to both threads at their initialization, or alternatively a static instance like the `multimap` one. Then simply replace the `multimap::insert` in the first thread by a `queue::push_back` of a `make_pair(key, value)`, and symmetrically in the consumer thread, fisrt have a `pop_front` of all the pending pairs in the queue, inserting them in the map at the same time, then implement your processing of your map, whatever it is.

Note:

Please be aware that if you are using a multimap, you might end up with multiple values for the same key: the call to `find` will return an iterator, and you might well have to check the next entries of the multimap to make sure you get all the values with the same keys .

Comment: In main thread loop I read the values of MultiMap for particular key. Can I do this way main thread?                                          
EnterCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);
     std::multimap<string,string>::iterator it = mymultimap.begin();
LeaveCriticalSection(&m_criticalsection);

Comment: @sandy If you only need a particular key, why not use `multimap::find`? Iterators aren't invalidated by insertion.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know why I did not recommend it initially, as it's usually what I do for my own projects. Anyway, glad to be of help.